# Validating a string format in VBA Access

Tags: regex, string, vba, ms-access

- I would like to write a Boolean function that checks that Medicaid IDs are in the required format.
- Namely 2 alpha characters followed by 5 digits followed by 1 alpha character.
- If the Medicaid ID is not available then 99999999 should be entered manually into the text box.

So it's either 9999999 or the required Medicaid formatted string that return a value of True.

Samples:

> AZ12345Z
>    NP54321J
>    EM17345P

So far I have 2 functions working together but I made a mess of the logic!!

Thank you

```
Public Function isAlpha(cChar As Integer) As Boolean
'returns true if its a alphabetic character
    isAlpha = IIf((cChar >= 65 And cChar <= 90) Or (cChar >= 97 And cChar <= 122), True, False)   
End Function

Public Function CheckMedicaidIDFormat(strMedicaidID As String) As Boolean
    Dim blnResult As Boolean
    If strMedicaidID = "99999999" or If Len(strMedicaidID) = 8 And isAlpha(Left(strMedicaidID, 2)) = True And IsNumeric(Mid(strMedicaidID, 3, 5)) = True And isAlpha(Right(strMedicaidID, 1)) = True Then 

        blnResult = True
    Else
        blnResult = False
    End If
    CheckMecicaidIDFormat = blnResult
End Function
```

Answer (score 6):

While `RegEx` is a good general solution for this type of problem, in this case a simple `Like` comparison will do

```
Function IsValid(strIn As String) As Boolean
    IsValid = (strIn Like "[A-Z][A-Z]#####[A-Z]") Or strIn = "99999999"
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this

```
Sub Test()
MsgBox IsValid("AZ12345Z")
MsgBox IsValid("1AZ12345Z")
End Sub
```

*test function*

```
Function IsValid(strIn As String) As Boolean
If strIn = "99999999" Then
IsValid = True
Else
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
.Pattern = "^[A-Z]{2}\d{5}[A-Z]$"
IsValid = .Test(strIn)
End With
End If
End Function
```

Comment: The _Beginning of string_ and _End of string_ patterns need to apply to both alternatives.  Also, OP want alternative to be 8 x 9's. Maybe `^(?:([A-Z]{2}\d{5}[A-Z])|([9]{8}))$` or `(^[A-Z]{2}\d{5}[A-Z]$)|(^[9]{8}$)`

Comment: @chrisneilsen fair points. Ive stripped back out the simple test out rather than add to the regexp.

Answer (score 0):

VBA has support for Regular Expressions using the COM `VBScript.RegExp` object, like so:

```
Dim regex As VBScript.RegExp
Set regex = New VBScript.RegExp ' or CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
regex.Pattern = "^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]\d\d\d\d\d[A-Za-z]$"

If medicId = "99999999" Or regex.Test( medicId ) Then
    ' code to handle valid Medicaid ID here
End If
```

Comment: I think OP wants an alpha character at start and end not alphanumeric.

Comment: I've never used VBScript in any of my Access databases. Very interesting solution. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Maria6460 This isn't VBScript. You're still using VBA, but making use of a component originally designed for VBScript (i.e. the regex class), but which is still fully-compatible with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is very suitable for this, but if you prefer not to use it (and many people do, for various reasons) it is very possible to do without.

You made a small mistake in the if statement in the CheckMediacaidIDFormat function. 'If' is mentioned twice and you forgot some parentheses. I would formulate like this:

```
Public Function CheckMedicaidIDFormat(strMedicaidID As String) As Boolean
    Dim blnResult As Boolean
    If strMedicaidID = "99999999" Or _
            (Len(strMedicaidID) = 8 And _
            isAlpha(Left(strMedicaidID, 2)) = True And _
            IsNumeric(Mid(strMedicaidID, 3, 5)) = True And _
            isAlpha(Right(strMedicaidID, 1)) = True) _
            Then

        blnResult = True
    Else
        blnResult = False
    End If
    CheckMecicaidIDFormat = blnResult
End Function
```

Note that I use line breaks (space followed by underscore in vba) for readability and parentheses around the 'And' conditions. You can do without the line breaks if you wish, but not without the parentheses.

Comment: Nice work. I think I'll need to use the mid function to check if the second character is alpha as well. Thanks for your time and effort.